# Persistent Storage (Gluster/Other storage) for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, glusterfs

I am trying to setup Kubernetes with Gluster using Heketi. After several tries, i am still not able to get it working. I am using RancherOS with Rancher application running on it which manages Kubernetes. I am now looking for alternative approaches.

1) Setup GlusterFS and Heketi on a standalone RHEL host:
In this case, my question is whether it's even possible to manage a Kubernetes cluster present on another set of hosts or do i need to have GlusterFS servers present on the same hosts that Kubernetes manages? If it's the former, then will i have to mount the gluster partition on Kubernetes node?

2) Kubernetes with any other persistent storage provider:
We cannot use cloud providers for sure. Paid ones are also not an option so i was considering *Ceph*. Anyone with successful implementation and whether we have something similar to Heketi for Ceph setup?

Comment: about 2: https://rook.io/ uses Ceph under the hood. I have no experience with it though

Answer (score 1):

@Technext, we can help you to configure heketi + gluster configuration in kubernetes setup. We have many users who has already configured the same. If you havent tried this please check gluster-kubernetes repo https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes.

Can you please let us know the error you are into when you deploy Heketi gluster ? We can try to help you to achieve this target.

Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for the link Humble. I actually forgot to update this post but i have finally managed to setup GlusterFS using Heketi. All is well now. :) Thanks.